# WebSphere Application Server 6.1 support for Java 1.6?

Tags: java, java-6, websphere-6.1

Can I use Java 1.6 with WebSphere Application Server 6.1? IBM's website says [no](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rovr_specs.html).

But I require Java 1.6 for a software application to be deployed and I cannot currently upgrade to Websphere 7.0, or use a different application server (WAS 6.1 is the org standard).

what are my options?

Thanks.

Comment: You have no options, other than upgrading the appserver to something from the 21st century, or sticking with Java 5. Sorry.

Comment: Others already answered, so just a thought: if WAS 6.1 is the org standard, then Java 1.5 is certainly also org standard, whether the org knows it or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nobody can stop you from trying to run WAS 6.1 with Java 6 but this configuration IS NOT SUPPORTED by IBM and according to [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=169612&tstart=0), I'm not even sure you'll be able to start WAS.

Comment: they must be doing something really interesting with the startup logic of the server if simply upgrading to a new JDK breaks the functionality

Answer (score 2):

Since websphere 6.1 does not support J2SE 6, your options are very limited.

*option 1*

- Talk to your upper management &
  convince them the need to switch to
  WAS 7.0

*option 2*

- Downgrade your code compatibility to 1.5 and compile for J2SE 5.0

*option 3*

- If you have a support contract with IBM, open a high priority ticket for getting 1.6 support on WAS 6.1

Comment: My money is on (3) to never happen

Comment: (3) is something to tell your 'suits' that you exhausted all options :) good times..